# How to get the scale on iPhone 6 to match storyboard scale?

Tags: ios, swift, scale, screen-resolution, iphone-6

I'm trying to crop a picture in a certain area in a imageView, but the wrong area keeps on getting cropped. I believe it is because the iPhone 6 has a higher resolution than the storyboard, but I'm not sure how to get it to match. I did some research, and I know it has something to do with points, pixels, and scale, but I'm not sure how to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

as you can see on this picture. Open up assistant editor. Go to Preview -> StoryBoard. In the left bottom corner click the Plus button. Choose the size you want the display of you Iphone to preview and make desired cropping.